# Quadratic Equation with Python and Flask

Tags: python, flask, quadratic

So currently I am trying to make a program using flask, but I am getting a `TypeError` when I run it, saying `The view function for 'post_factors' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.` and I cannot figure how to fix it. Here is the code:

```
import math

def dofactors(a, b, c):
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    c = int(c)
    d = b**2-4*a*c # discriminant

    if d < 0:
        result = 'No solutions'
    elif d == 0:
        x1 = -b / (2*a)
        result = f'The sole solution is {str(x1)}'
    else: # if d > 0
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d)) / (2*a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(d)) / (2*a)
        result = f'Solutions are {str(x1)} and {str(x2)}'

    return(result)
```

and the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form method="POST">
  <p><h1>Factorizer</h1></p>
    <p>please enter your variable values assuming the form ax^2+bx+c</p>
  <input type="text", placeholder="a", name="a" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
  <input type="text", placeholder="b", name="b" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
  <input type="text", placeholder="c", name="c" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

EDIT: I forgot to include the code that is calling it in the main class, here it is:

```
@app.route('/factors')
def form_factors():
    return render_template('factors.html')
```

and the POST function:

```
@app.route('/factors', methods=['POST'])
def post_factors():
    a = str(request.form['a'])
    b = str(request.form['b'])
    c = str(request.form['c'])
    dofactors(a, b, c)
```

Comment: if a is 0 you will have an unhandled exception, which will make the function not return anything

Comment: When I run the program I use a = 1, b = 4, and c = 21 for testing

Comment: `post_factors()` doesn't return anything - it calls `dofactors()` which does, but you're throwing its return value away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning values in your `dofactor` function, but these 'return's don't apply to the route as they are in a different scope. You could fix this with the following in your `post_factors` route.

```
return(dofactors(a, b, c))
```